# Securing my API using self signed certificate in c#

Tags: c#, api, https

I want to protect my application from mitm attacks with fiddler and other web debuggers. I also want to use a self signed HTTPS certificate just for the API. How can I verify the certificate fingerprint/serial number in C#? I'm using HTTPWebRequests to make my calls.

(The application will be securely packed to prevent fingerprint tampering on the client.)

Comment: Are you trying to use self signed certificate during development or in production? I wouldn't advice you to use it in production

Comment: Production, but why is it a bad idea? Fiddler can bypass even a signed one.

Comment: Its a bad idea because its self signed and your users will be shown a warning telling them that the certificate is untrusted and that they should not proceed with opening the link. Self signed certificate is meant to be used during development alone.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this?

**X509Certificate2.Verify()**:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify.aspx